Outlook w/ on prem exchange, multiple users sharing one mailbox best practices
At work, I manage a mailbox named "info" that approximately 35-40 users utilize, causing significant issues:

Initially, when added as an additional user mailbox, it functions correctly. However, after some time, using the "reply all"-function, results in the mailbox adding itself to the reply.

When allowing it to auto-map or manually opening it, the same issue eventually occurs. Additionally, users are unable to access the delegated mailbox's contact list.

I've attempted granting "send as" access via the Exchange Admin Center (EAC) and adding "Full Access" via Exchange Shell with auto-mapping disabled. Creating a second account on the profile with user credentials works for some users (2-3), but fails for others.


This mailbox must remain a User Mailbox because certain users need to connect to it on mobile devices. Shared mailboxes do not function correctly on mobile devices with an on-premises Exchange server. Another important consideration: many users work on a terminal server session, where adding more than one account seems problematic. Errors such as "Cannot expand the folder. Network problems are preventing connection to Microsoft Exchange" or "An unexpected error has occurred" frequently occur with a few emails.
I've exhausted various solutions found online, but none have provided a lasting fix—some solutions last only a few weeks, days, or even hours. Additionally, what works for one user does not necessarily work for another.
What are the best practices or fixes to make sure all my users have a seamless experience and I stop wasting time trying to fix Outlook profiles?
At this moment my user are setup like this:
User Mailbox: Dispatch1
Additional user mailbox : Info, manually added and Delegated to Dispatch1
Additional shared Mailboxes :  box1, box2, box3, box4.  Delegated and auto mapped to info and dispatch1
I have attempted to delegate boxes 1-4 solely to Info, or to both the user and Info. I have not yet removed delegation to Info and assigned it directly to the users who need those boxes, due to the workload and potential issues that may arise from this change.

Make sure permissions on the Root/Top of information store are adjusted as well.You can try to use "Set-MailboxFolderPermission" to delegate  "FolderVisible".Refer to Set-MailboxFolderPermission
And my experience is that you're better off not setting up complex nested permissions like this, and it's better to just grant access to the four shared mailboxes to the user

I have the following suggestions:

Convert the mailbox to Shared
Grant Full Access and SendAs to the users
Don't add the account manually in Outlook, use Automapping
For mobile access to the shared mailbox, enable the account in Active Directory and manually set a password. Now you can enter that password in the mobile devices

